# Dash(Python) - thicker ring in gauge meter of dash-daq

Tags: python, css, python-3.x, plotly-dash, plotly-python

The ring that [`dash_daq.Gauge`](https://dash.plot.ly/dash-daq/gauge) outputs is too thin, as you can see from the picture below.
[image: gauge meter with thin ring]
I would like to have thicker ring. I couldn’t find css element under ‘inspect element’ to increase the thickness of ring. How do i go about doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just create an `assets` folder and place there your `css` file e.g. "styles.css" and it works fine (Dash v1.6.0)

styles.css:

```
circle {
    stroke-width: 20px;
}
```

app.py:

```
import dash
import dash_daq as daq
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

app = dash.Dash(__name__, assets_folder = 'assets', include_assets_files = True)

app.layout = html.Div([
    daq.Gauge(
        id='my-gauge',
        label="Default",
        value=6,
        style={'display': 'block' }
    ),
    dcc.Slider(
        id='my-gauge-slider',
        min=0,
        max=10,
        step=1,
        value=5
    ),
])

@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('my-gauge', 'value'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('my-gauge-slider', 'value')]
)
def update_output(value):
    return value

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

gauge meter is made up of svg tag. To get an idea i will show the screen shot

[image]

Try changing the stroke-width attr value to change the thinkness. i hope this will help you to get inital idea.

Comment: thanks and yes, i got the initial idea and that changed the width from within the "inspect element". But, I couldn't find the name of `css` class to put in my `base.css` file. I've tried `.track`, `.track-progress`, `circle-track`, `.circle-track-progress`, `.sc-iwsKbI cRfgdB-track` and many other with `stroke-width:10;` inside them and none worked. Please help me with this.

Comment: ok. so, the thickness simply can't be changed by changing the attribute in `base.css` file?

Comment: yes you are right. simple js example  document.getElementById('svgShapeId').setAttribute('stroke-width',150);

Comment: TBH, i don't know javascript at all. i made a new `text document.js` in assets folder with nothing but `function myFunction() {
document.getElementById('svgShapeId').setAttribute('stroke-width',150);
}` inside and it's not working.